# saving ref of another document with mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am new using mongodb and i am practicing with ref and populate... but i have a silly problem.

i am receiving from my client a object like this.

```
    {
    "name": "Jhon"
    "books": [
              { 
                "title": "whatever",
                 "pages": 300
              },
              {
                "title": "otherBook",
                 "pages": 450
              }
             ]
    }
```

So i have two schemas, authorSchema and booksSchema... so what i pretend is save the books and take the _id of each book to save the author with it.

My code in nodejs

```
authorCtrl.saveAuthor = (req, res) => {

    var booksId= []

    for (i = 0; i < req.body.books.length; i++) {
        booksModel.create(req.body.books[i], function (err, book) {
            booksId.push(book._id)
        })
    }

    var author= {
        name: req.body.name,
        books: booksId
    }

    console.log(author) // here i check and books array is empty,

    authorModel.create(author).then((authorSaved) => {
        res.json(authorSaved)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.json(err)
    })
}
```

i know it is an asynchronous problem... but how can i do it??.. or what is the best practice to ref collections?

/////EDIT//////

Here are my schemas

Authors Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose;


const authorsSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    books: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'books'
    }]
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('authors', authorsSchema);
```

Books Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose;


const booksSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    pages: { type: Number }

})


module.exports = mongoose.model('books', booksSchema);
```

Comment: can you post your schemas too?

Comment: @ArootinAghazaryan posted, thank you for check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authors Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const authorsSchema = new Schema({
    name:  String,
    books: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Book'
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', authorsSchema);
```

Books Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const booksSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    pages: Number,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', booksSchema);
```

NodeJS Code:

```
const author = {
        name: req.body.name
    }

AuthorModel.create(author, (error, createdAuthor)=>{
  //handle error

        BookModel.insertMany(req.body.books, function (err, createdbooks) {
            // handle error
            createdAuthor.books.push(createdbooks); 
            createdAuthor.save();
        })   
}
```

Comment: it has sense... but is not working... i have this error 

(node:11848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 5c6e2373c5a2a62e48f0deed

Comment: i checked the mongoshell and i have one author but just one book... and i sent two books from my client, but the books are added well

Comment: it's because it's not possible to save() a document multiple times. look at my edit. i took the save() out of the loop. it should work fine now.

Comment: it is not saving the books inside the AuthorSchema... i check the collection and the array is empty, but the book was added... damn this is getting me crazy

Comment: let me think :) this is an async problem. the save() is being called before the Book is created!

Comment: haha yes, take your time man! i apreciate it... i am 4 hours thinking it... as i mentioned it is an asynchronous problem... butttttt... it has to have a solution!

Comment: you found it man :) , thanks a lot, with insertMany i solved that problem. i edited your post, THANKS AGAIN!!! i owe you one

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

authorCtrl.saveAuthor = (req, res) => {
var booksId= [];

for (var i = req.body.books.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    booksModel.create(req.body.books[i], (err, book) => {
        booksId.push(book._id);
        if(i == 0) { // This if condition executes at the end of the for loop.
            var author= {
                name: req.body.name,
                books: booksId
            };

            console.log(author);

            authorModel.create(author).then((authorSaved) => {
                res.json(authorSaved);
            }).catch(err => {
                res.json(err);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Javascript promises as below:

```
            var booksId = [];
            var promises = [];
            req.body.books.forEach(element => {
                promises.push(insertBook(element));
            });
            Promise.all(promises)    
            .then(function(data){ 
                /* do stuff when success */
                console.log('##GREAT##',booksId);
                /*** INSERT ARRAY OF BOOK IDs INTO authorModel***/
            })
            .catch(function(err){ 
                /* error handling */ 
            });

            function insertBook(element){
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                    var book = new booksModel({
                        title: element.title,
                        page:  element.page  
                    });

                    book.save(function(err,data){
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                            reject(err)
                        }else{
                            console.log('#success');
                            booksId.push(data._id)
                            resolve();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```